# PHP Application loading slow after database size increased gradually

Tags: php, page-load-time, load-time

I am running MVC PHP application. After some times when database size increased gradually the application get slowed. Is there any specific reason of database size. How can I reduce the load time?

Comment: u can index tables it will help to speed up little bit. Check the link below for indexing       https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-indexes.html

Comment: explain your queries with the EXPLAIN keyword. This will help you to understand where the query is taking time to complete the execution. Refer this link for more details.https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain.html

Comment: indexing table helped me little

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Optimize your query and your code,
display and select only the fields that is needed, do not select *,
also, you can use ajax to make the loading faster, since multiple users opening a php page simultaneously will slowdown the execution of your query